# Identical p values of normalized and non-normalized datas

Tags: pandas, scipy, anova, p-value

I am trying to implement a one-way anova on 3 groups of plantgrowth (ctrl, trt1, trt2) on this dataset http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/PlantGrowth.csv. I am using a combination of Pandas and Scipy.  However, the f and p-values by performing a column-wise z-score normalization of the data are **identical** to those without performing normalization! Can anyone tell me why that is the case?

```
    import pandas as pd
    import math
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy import stats

    import pandas as pd
    datafile="../data/PlantGrowth.csv"
    data = pd.read_csv(datafile)

    weight_zscore = 'weight' + '_zscore'
    data['weight_zscore'] = (data['weight']-       data['weight'].mean()/data['weight'].std(ddof=0))


    grps = pd.unique(data.group.values)
    weight_data = {grp:data['weight'][data.group == grp] for grp in grps}
    weight_zscore_data = {grp:data['weight_zscore'][data.group == grp] for grp in grps}


    F, p = stats.f_oneway(weight_data['ctrl'], weight_data['trt1'], weight_data['trt2'])
    Fz, pz = stats.f_oneway(weight_zscore_data['ctrl'], weight_zscore_data['trt1'], weight_zscore_data['trt2'])
    print "Non-Normalized weight": F, p, 
    print "Normalized weight": Fz, pz
```

The answer is:

```
    Non-normalized weight: 4.84608786238, 0.0159099583256 
    Normalized weight: 4.84608786238, 0.0159099583256
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that because the normalization is a bijective transformation of the dataset, it is not going to affect the results of the statistical test. For example, if you were doing a means test, by subtracting `5` from each mean, you would not affect the results of the test. Similarly, by dividing the mean by a value, or even the whole dataset, you wouldn't affect the p-values or other scores you can compute off of this.

Comment: Thank you! Was thinking exactly the same. Was praying that somebody told me otherwise, because I _need_ smaller p-values on another dataset. :D 
Cheers! Thank you, Mr Coman.